# Who is this character in the mid-season finale of Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, marvel, agents-of-shield

At the end of the mid-season finale of season 2, we see

> a man without eyes who has his own copy of the Obelisk, which glows when Skye and Raina place their Obelisk in the temple.

Who is the man?

> [image: who is this man?]

Comment: He looks scary...

Comment: He looks like a rehash from X-Files.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its more than likely that the man with no eyes is "[Reader](http://marvel.wikia.com/Reader_%28Inhuman%29_%28Earth-616%29)", an inhuman character who is blind but has the ability to make anything he 'reads' become real.

He is a very powerful figure in the Inhumans canon, and the Inhumans themselves blinded him because he was perceived to be *too* powerful.

Comment: His appearance (and the phone call he made) seems to indicate that there is an underground "community" of Inhumans around the world. This is probably the MCU version of them hiding from humans by moving the city around. I would imagine they will be actively looking for Skye & Raina in future episodes.

Answer (score 4):

As S02E11 *Aftershocks* of *Marvel's Agents of S.H.I.E.L.D.* revealed that the eyeless guy

> is an Inhuman who has power of teleportation. His Inhuman name hasn't been revealed yet, but he was called Gordon in flashback.

Comment: He was called Gordon in the flashback to 1983